# GtkTreeView::row-activated : Avoid continuous signal emission

Tags: callback, treeview, gtk, signals, gtkada

I have a treeview and I am watching for the "row-activated" signal. I'm using a Callback to handle the row activation of elements of a GKT.TREE_VIEW. This signal is emitted when the user double clicks a treeview row or when a row is selected and on of the keys : Space, Shift+Space, Return or Enter is pressed.
The problem is that the signal is being continuously emitted when one of those keys is pressed.

Is there any way to get this signal is only emitted only when the key is released? Or can I get the state of the keys when the signal is emitted to control my custom Callback Handler?